# Square root of negative zero

Tags: floating-point, g++4.8

Under g++ version 4.8.0 (32-bit mingw), the square root of -0.0 (binary representation 0x8000000000000000) is NAN. But I could have sworn that earlier versions (I'm not sure which, but the last time I ran my full test suite) returned simply 0.0, which seems more sensible to me.

Is this right? Has something in the C++ standard changed, or is this a g++ change?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a non-standard* behavior of the MinGW environment (that I have also observed, indirectly, through a customer for whom the software I work on was failing unexpectedly).

You may have seen the correct result for `sqrt(-0.)`, i.e. `-0.`, with a higher optimization level where the value was computed correctly at compile-time, or with a previous version of the run-time in which the bug was not present.

I ended up defining my own “fixed” `sqrt()` as:

```
double mysqrt(double x) {
  if (x == 0.) return x; else return sqrt(x);
}
```

---

(*) IEEE 754 defines `sqrt(-0.)` as `-0.`. A C or C++ compiler does not have to implement IEEE 754 for floating-point arithmetic, but GCC tries to (and in this particular instance, fails).

Comment: I think technically GCC is just the compiler and linker and not all of the standard library facilities. The GCC documentation says the user has to supply some of the library facilities. So GCC does not try to provide `sqrt`, so it does not fail to produce the correct result for `sqrt(-0.)`. In MinGW, the libraries come from the Windows environment.

Comment: From [the GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Standards.html#Standards): “GCC does not provide the library facilities required only of hosted implementations, nor yet all the facilities required by C99 of freestanding implementations; to use the facilities of a hosted environment, you will need to find them elsewhere (for example, in the GNU C library).”

Comment: Thanks for this! I was beginning to wonder whether I'd imagined the earlier behaviour.

Comment: Any idea what rationale there might be for having a value of x where 1/sqrt(x) is negative?  As I see it, IEEE 754 is supposed to balance mathematical accuracy, ease of implementation, and ease of use; most of its design decisions favor at least one of those.  Having 1/sqrt(negZero) return negZero wouldn't seem to particularly fit any.

Comment: @supercat I do not have an explanation. I suspect that somewhere lurks a vehement article by William Kahan on how prolonging `sqrt()` in `-0.` along its tangent it simplifies such or such numerical algorithm. Note that the special cases IEEE 754 defines for `pow()` are simpler.

Comment: @pascalcuoq: you're looking for "branch cuts in the complex plane: or, much ado about nothing's sign bit."  (tl:dr - consider sqrt(x +/- 0i); basically everything falls out from the symmetry you want sqrt to have on C).

Comment: @StephenCanon Dang, I already moved this question to a question. You will have to provide your answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236117/what-numerical-algorithm-is-simplified-by-defining-sqrt-0-0-as-0-0

Comment: @StephenCanon Having read the beginning of the article in question, I now realize that while the question is fine here, the answer may be off-topic for StackOverflow. I am not going to finish the article tonight, and I have done more maths than the majority of programmers. In fact, I requested asylum from the CS department on the very semester I was supposed to study complex analysis.

Comment: @StephenCanon: can you elaborate on your comment about the complex sqrt symmetries? As far as I can see, you definitely want `sqrt(conj(z)) == conj(sqrt(z))` for all finite `z`, and given the usual choice of branch cut for complex sqrt, I guess you'd also expect something like `i * sqrt(-z) == copysign(1, imag(z)) * sqrt(z)` to be true for all finite `z`.  Those symmetries lead you to `sqrt(-0.0 + 0.0i) == 0.0 + 0.0i` (as in Kahan's paper and in C99 Annex G), but I don't see how any of this would suggest `sqrt(-0.0) == -0.0` in the real case.