# What numerical algorithm is simplified by defining sqrt(-0.0) as -0.0?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

The IEEE 754 standard defines the square root of negative zero as negative zero. This choice is easy enough to rationalize, but other choices, such as defining `sqrt(-0.0)` as `NaN`, can be rationalized too and are easier to implement in hardware. If the fear was that programmers would write `if (x >= 0.0) then sqrt(x) else 0.0` and be bitten by this expression evaluating to `NaN` when `x` is `-0.0`, then `sqrt(-0.0)` could have been defined as `+0.0` (actually, for this particular expression, the results would be even more consistent).

Is there a numerical algorithm in particular where having `sqrt(-0.0)` defined as `-0.0` simplifies the logic of the algorithm itself?

Comment: The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_zero) is decent.  You probably ought to ask this at math.se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only mathematically reasonable result is 0.  There is a reasonable question of whether it should be +0 or -0.  For most computations it makes no difference at all, but there are some specific complex expressions for which the result makes more sense under the -0 convention.  The exact details are outside the scope of this site, but that's the gist of it.

I may explain some more when I'm not on vacation, if someone else doesn't beat me to it.

Comment: This is really a non-answer. What are some expressions where the -0 convention makes more sense?

Comment: @pburka Examples are in the article “Elementary Functions or Much Ado About Nothing's Sign Bit”, the authoritative reference which Stephen pointed out before this question was a StackOverflow Question: http://people.freebsd.org/~das/kahan86branch.pdf . As he says, the exact details are outside the scope of “programming”. The programmer should, at least in the case of `sqrt(-0.0)`, “Rather than think of +0 and -0 as distinct numerical values, think of their sign bit as an auxiliary variable that conveys one bit of information (or misinformation)”, and trust the mathematician that it makes sense

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Oddly enough, Kahan's sign bit article is the one that convinced me that `sqrt(-0.0)` being `0.0` would have made more sense, for consistency with the way that Kahan defines the complex square root.  If I'm reading it right, the result of a CSQRT call (on a finite input) always has a real part whose sign bit is unset.  (And I believe that's the behaviour that C99 Annex G recommends, too.)  IOW, CSQRT always maps quadrants 1 and 2 to quadrant 1 and quadrants 3 and 4 to quadrant 4. (Using the sign of the zero to determine quadrant membership in the obvious way.)

Answer (score 4):

It was defined in the official floating point standard in 1985 (IEEE std. 754-1985) that sqrt(-0.0) = -0.0.

The 2008 revision of the same standard added a definition of the pow function. According to this definition, pow(x,y) can have a negative sign only if y is an odd integer. Hence, pow(-0.0, 3.0) = -0.0. While pow(-0.0, 0.5) = +0.0. In 2008, it was too late to change the definition of sqrt(-0.0) and therefore we have the unfortunate situation that the two functions give different results.

The sign of zero generally doesn't matter since zero and negative zero are equal. But it matters when you divide by it. So 1/sqrt(-0.0) gives -INF, while pow(-0.0,-0.5) gives +INF.

The decision of 1985 was probably just an observation of status quo. The Intel math coprocessor 8087 from 1980 had sqrt implemented in hardware and it gave sqrt(-0.0) = -0.0. Today, all PC processors have sqrt implemented in hardware, so it would be very difficult to change the standard. The problem is not so important that it is worthwhile making two different sqrt functions that differ only for negative zero. I don't know anything about the history prior to 1980. If anybody can trace the history further back please post a comment here.