# sqrt is only defined when argument is nonnegative

Tags: c, gcc, math.h, sqrt

This compiles fine

```
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    double i = sqrt(9.0);
}
```

If I change 9.0 to -9.0, then my compiler (GNU C) gives an error about an undefined reference to 'sqrt'.

I was expecting the sqrt function to return NaN or an exception. How does the C library only define sqrt for non-negative arguments?

Comment: Side note: An odd-ball is that `sqrt(-0.0)` will return `-0.0` on many systems (IEEE 754) [Square root of negative zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232157/square-root-of-negative-zero)  So a pseudo exception to "sqrt is only defined when argument is nonnegative".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is happening because `gcc` can use *builtin functions* during the optimization process to compute certain functions including `sqrt` at compile time in many but not all cases. If that is the case it will not need to emit a call to `sqrt` and therefore will not need to link against `libm`.

The gcc documents have a [complete list of builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), and it says (*emphasis mine*):

> The remaining functions are provided **for optimization purposes**.
>
> GCC includes built-in versions of many of the functions in the standard C library. The versions prefixed with _*builtin* are always treated as having the same meaning as the C library function even if you specify the -fno-builtin option. (see C Dialect Options) **Many of these functions are only optimized in certain cases**; if they are not optimized in a particular case, a call to the library function is emitted.

If I compile this code with `gcc -S` and look at the assembly emitted(*[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b0297c57fcf5bac)*) when we use `sqrt(9.0)` then `gcc` will use a builtin and not emit a call to *sqrt* at all since it will compute it at compile time. If we change the code to use `sqrt(-9.0)` it will now emit(*[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc2b25113d8f2d7f)*):

```
call    sqrt
```

which will require linking with libm, the fix would be to add `-lm` to the end of your compile options.

In the case of `sqrt(-9)` we have a *domain error*, if go to the C99 draft standard section `7.12.7.5` *The sqrt functions* paragraph *2* says (*emphasis mine*):

> The sqrt functions compute the nonnegative square root of x. **A domain error occurs if
>   the argument is less than zero**.

If we go back to `7.12.1` *Treatment of error conditions* it says:

> [...] On a domain error, the function returns an implementation-defined value; if the integer expression **math_errhandling & MATH_ERRNO** is nonzero, the integer expression
>   errno acquires the value **EDOM**; if the integer expression **math_errhandling &
>   MATH_ERREXCEPT** is nonzero, the ‘‘invalid’’ floating-point exception is raised.

so either *errno* will be set and/or a *floating point* exception will be raised which seems like a case where `gcc` would decided it is not efficient to optimize.

Comment: gcc may also optimize sqrt(const) away and replace it with the result if it calculate it. sqrt on a negative number is probably something gcc does not want to deal with so it generates the code to let real sqrt function deal with it in that case. Linking with `-lm` would probably fix the undefined reference error.

Comment: 'builtin' just means that gcc uses its own implementation of the well-known function. Considering that gcc knows what that function does, it allows optimizer to eliminate constant expressions. If you compile the code with -O0, it would retain reference to real sqrt() regardless of the argument sign. Having builtin alone is not sufficient for elimination of the reference.

Comment: The reason `sqrt` on a negative number cannot be optimized out is that it has to report the error either via floating point exceptions or in `errno` (or both); GCC is not equipped to arrange for this, and it would not be efficient to inline doing this anyway.

Comment: @ArtemB I clarified, although using `-O0` does not force a call to sqrt although using `-fno-builtin` does.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Interesting. So, in effect builtin-related optimizations are still in effect even with -O0. I've checked with clang 3.4 and it also eliminates sqrt(9.0) even with -O0.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably, you forgot to link `libm`. Change your command line:

```
gcc -o foo2 foo2.c -lm
```

I suspect that based on the type of argument, `sqrt()` is either expanded into an inline instruction or into a library call.

Answer (score 0):

The square root of a negative number is a [complex number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number). C's `sqrt()` function (via `math.h`) does not return a `complex` type, but a `double`. You can check `errno` for error conditions when passing this function a negative value; refer to the [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/sqrt.html) for more information:

> For finite values of x < -0, a domain error shall occur, and either a NaN (if supported), or an implementation-defined value shall be returned.

If you want to use `complex` types, include [`complex.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex.h) and use `csqrt()`, instead.

Comment: The OP can't check errno, nor does he mention getting a domain error. The OP's problem is *it does not compile*.

Answer (score 0):

```
//gcc -std=c99 csqrt.c -lm 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

void print_complex(double complex c){
    double i = cimag(c);
    printf("%g %c %gi",
        creal(c),
        i >= 0. ? '+'
                : '-',
        fabs(i));
}

int main(){
    double complex z = csqrt(-9.0);
    print_complex(z);//0 + 3i
}
```